to_datetime alterando os valores de coluna
Boa noite,
ao transformar o formato da minha coluna para "datetime64", esta criando uma data e hora fictícia e jogando os dados existentes na minha coluna para o fim da hora.
df = pd.read_excel("Mov Prod.xlsx")

df["TTDTE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TTDTE"])

exemplos de valores originais: 20240101
saida:
1970-01-01 00:00:00.020240101

Isto acontece porque você não passou o formato da data esperado, no seu caso  %Y%m%d
Veja exemplo:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"TTDTE": [20240101, 20241010]})

>>> df
      TTDTE
0  20240101
1  20241010

>>> pd.to_datetime(df["TTDTE"], format="%Y%m%d")
0   2024-01-01
1   2024-10-10
Name: TTDTE, dtype: datetime64[ns]

Basta atribuir à uma outra coluna, ou à mesma.
>>> df["TTDTE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["TTDTE"], format="%Y%m%d")

>>> df
       TTDTE
0 2024-01-01
1 2024-10-10

Veja a documentação do to_datetime
